# Why plain strings are considered bug free?

Tags: javascript

In the code if I have the following line of code doesn't throw an error:

```
'any string'
console.log('test');
```

Obviously this throws:

```
'any string' console.log('test'); // missing ;
```

But not this: `'any string'; console.log('test');`

I mean the 'any string' has nothing to do in the script but it is considered bug free, why?

Comment: For the same reason `5;` is not a bug?

Comment: The reason `5;` and `'foo';` works is due to the same interpreter that allows your `console.log();` call to work without forcing the output to a variable.

Comment: Automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) occurs when two lines cannot be understood as a single line. In this case, clearly the two lines cannot be understood together without a semicolon, so ASI does apply.

Comment: I know the automatic semi-colon insertion but was talking about the 'any string' which I get the right answer from @Scimonster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is just an expression - JS doesn't differentiate between function calls and ordinary expressions.

In the first case, a semicolon is automatically placed at the end of the first line, breaking it up. That clearly doesn't exist in the second example. In the third, again, you break them up into different expressions.

Even `console.log()` is an expression - it is a function call that returns `undefined` and has side effects.

This effect is intentionally used to force strict mode interpretation. A strict-mode function is written as:

```
function myFunc() {
"use strict"; // just the plain string
// function body
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer for dummy question.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript statements are terminated by semicolons: `;`, in theory.

However, JS has the idea of **semicolon insertion**, where semicolons can be inserted into code under certain conditions - specifically, after `}` or newlines (see ["Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion" in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9)).

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript engine in most browsers is not that strict than what you would expect from other languages e.g. compiled C.

Therefore it is a good idea to sometimes check your JavaScript code with a static analysis tool like [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Pasting your snippet into it gives

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
>
> 'any string'
>
> line 1 character 13 Expected ';' and instead saw 'console'.
>
> 'any string'
>
> line 2 character 1 'console' was used before it was defined.
>
> console.log('test');